# after ldaps config, ldapsearch does not display entries

Tags: ldap, openldap

I configured ldaps by refering http://linuxtechres.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-configure-ldaps-or-starttls.html.
after that when I try to  ldapsearch, it wont display any resulsts.
entries are there in ldap, as I will get error if I try to ldapadd them .
If I remove TLS related info from ldap.conf and slapd.conf , ldapsearch works nicely and display all entries.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some minimum level of confidentiality required in your config file?  Also the way the ACLs work is that they stop processing after the first hit (in general) so if you have an ACL on a specific user type that is extremely limiting that may be what causes your situation.  The admin account can always see everything in case you do mess things up.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late for this, but... Have you tried the ldapsearch/ldapadd option "`-ZZ`"?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is look at the slapd.log file and see what error the OpenLDAP server is returning when you try to connect.  Then you will have a hint of where to go next.